# React show/hide content

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a toggle content button with React. But I can only get it to open, not to close when I click on it again. Can someone please take a look and let me know what I need to change within the code to accomplish it?

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            activeLocation: 0,
        }
    }

  changeActiveLocation = (activeLocation) => {
        this.setState({
            activeLocation: activeLocation,
        });
    }

  render() {
    const activeLocation = company.locations[this.state.activeLocation];

    return (
      {company.locations.map((location, index) => (
      <div className="test-item">
        <div className="test-item-container" onClick={() => {this.changeActiveLocation(index)}}>
          <div className="test-item-header">
            <h3>Text goes here!</h3>
            <a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={(this.state.activeLocation === index) ? 'times' : 'chevron-right'} /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend creating a sandbox out of it. For me at least it is not clear how your toggle is working

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the active location to be the same location that you've clicked already so the `this.state.activeLocation === index` is always true. I would refactor the locations to their own component with an `isOpen` state value that gets updated when the location is clicked. So like the following:

```
// test class
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            activeLocation: 0,
        }
    }

  changeActiveLocation = (activeLocation) => {
        this.setState({
            activeLocation: activeLocation,
        });
    }

  render() {
    const activeLocation = company.locations[this.state.activeLocation];

    return (
      {company.locations.map((location, index) => (
          <LocationItem location={location} onClick={() => this.changeActiveLocation(index)} />
      ))}
    )
  }
}

// LocationItem
class LocationItem extends React.Component {
    state = { isOpen: false };

    handleClick = () => {
     this.setState(prevState => { isOpen: !prevState.isOpen});
     // call parent click to set new active location if that's still needed
     if(this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick;
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="test-item">
        <div className="test-item-container" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <div className="test-item-header">
            <h3>Text goes here!</h3>
            <a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={(this.state.isOpen ? 'times' : 'chevron-right'} /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice tip! In any case you should be careful with the handleClick, `!isOpen` will be undefined. Use prevState with setState like: 
`setState(prevState => ({ isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }))`

Comment: Good call, I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! But I was wondering if it's possible to do it without pulling out as a new component? So, within the existing code?

Comment: You could but the state would be harder to manage since each individual location would have their own open/close state. I would convert the `activeLocation` in state to an object with an index and an open state internally. Then, you'd set the open and index on the click and toggle accordingly.

Comment: Frankly, it would be much easier to just pull that piece out and more the "React" way so that each isolated part of the UI manages their own internal state.